# Почему символ из шрифта рисуется как 2 разных элемента?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .netcore2.0

Столкнулся с проблемой отрисовки шрифта, не могу понять почему так происходит. То ли это проблема шрифта, то ли нативная отрисовка в .net

Использую библиотеку `CoreCompact.System.Drawing` для `.NET Core 2.0`.
Отрисовываю с помощью `GraphicsPath.AddString` и `Graphics.DrawPath`.

При отрисовке с помощью `Graphics.DrawString` всё прекрасно.
Шрифт не из стандартных, загружаю из ресурсов сборки (из `Stream`).

`Graphics.DrawPath` использую для того, чтобы отрисовать обводку у текста.

[image: Буква Д]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Проблема была в свойстве `FillMode` у `GraphicsPath`. Выставил его в `FillMode.Winding`.

Но проблема осталось с обводкой.

[image: Буква Д]

Нашел альтернативный вариант решения: **сначала отрисовать обводку, а поверх неё отрисовать саму букву**.

Буду признателен, если кто-то подскажет решение получше.